# Can't read strings from keyboard (Java)

Tags: java

I am new to `java` and I need a little help. I wrote this code but it skips to the end and don't let me write anything in console..

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exercise21 {
   public static void main(String[] args){

      Scanner keyboardInput = new Scanner("System.in");
      String text = "";
      String text2 = "";

      System.out.println("Type any text : ");
      if(keyboardInput.hasNextLine()) text = keyboardInput.nextLine();

      System.out.println("Type the word you want to find : ");
      if(keyboardInput.hasNextLine()) text2 = keyboardInput.nextLine();

      System.out.println("Your word was found : " + text.indexOf(text2,0));

   }
}
```

Comment: "System.in" should not be within quotation marks

Comment: I noticed,tkank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it skips to the end is because at the start, there is nothing inside your `keyboardInput`, which causes the following 2 if checks to fail.

Simply removing the if checks will solve your problem, then afterwards you can do checks to make sure that the input isn't empty. Alternatively, you can wrap each input inside a while loop.

```
do {
    text = keyboardInput.nextLine();
} while (!text.equals(""))
```

which will keep on asking for input if the value is an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

It like this, Program will wait for 3 inputs for below.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int n,r,c;
n = in.nextInt();
r = in.nextInt();
c = in.nextInt();
```

Use `in.nextLine()` for Strings.

Answer (score 0):

your scanner can't found any line with the method `hasNextLine()` because your text has not been entered yet (This method is useful when reading a text from a file).

if you want to wait for the user to enter a text use 
`text = keyboardInput.nextLine();`
and remove the `if` statement

ps: as the other said you should also have `Scanner keyboardInput = new Scanner(System.in);` without the "